# JQuery - Show/hide multiple divs with the same class independently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a collapsible DIV like this:
If you click on the picture (which is in the table and comes with `show` class) the hidden div slides down (the one with the `content` class) with it's content and if you click on the hide button or anywhere else on the page, the `content` div will slide up.
I want to use multiple tables and hidden divs on the page (with the same classes) so i want to make sure to open them independently.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asfd0aot/) document, hope that someone can help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to at least attempt to do it yourself - this is not a free code writing service

Comment: Sorry, i changed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it with data attributes

```
<table width="502" style="border:1px solid black; background-color:white;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="300" style="padding:5px">
      Blablabla
    </td>
    <td width="200">
      <a class="show" data-id="1" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="content" data-id="1">
  <div class="content-inner">

    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x400">
    <p>
      More blablabla
    </p>

    <p class="hide" style="padding-top:50px">Hide</p>
  </div>
</div>

<table width="502" style="border:1px solid black; background-color:white;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="300" style="padding:5px">
      Blablabla
    </td>
    <td width="200">
      <a class="show" data-id="2" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="content" data-id="2">
  <div class="content-inner">

    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x400">
    <p>
      More blablabla
    </p>

    <p class="hide" style="padding-top:50px">Hide</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and change the JS like this

```
$('.show, .hide').click(function(){
var id = $(this).data('id');

  $('.content[data-id="'+id+'"]').slideToggle('2000', "swing", function() {
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Could you help me with the click-anywhere-to-close problem?

Comment: $('body').click(function(){
$('.content').slideUp();
});
$('.show, .hide').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
  $('.content').slideToggle('2000', "swing", function() {
  });
  return false;
});

Comment: that code resolves your "click anywhere else" , not the preventDefault and the return false in the function, they avoid the event bubbling

Comment: It's not working! @Pietro Could you help with the last comment?

Comment: One more thing @Pietro: i don't want to close the the `content` DIV if i click inside just if i click outside of the box. How could i achieve this?

Comment: Ok, fiddle updated, please note that this can be improved a lot (i am sleeping) https://jsfiddle.net/asfd0aot/4/   hope it helped ;)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply - thank you @Pietro ! Is it possible to have just one `content` DIV opened? So if you open a hidden DIV then the others will close? Many thanks again!

Comment: Thank you very much @Pietro !!! Unfortunately it does not work properly... If i open the first DIV then close it, some bug appears.

Comment: ok, I'm sure there's a cleaner solution (like using a lib for accordion) but this should fix your problem  https://jsfiddle.net/asfd0aot/6/

Comment: If i click inside the DIV twice, it closes itself @Pietro